# Script to change strings in several files

Tags: java, replace

I would like from my current folder containing Java files, to replace:

```
ColorTee.testh = new TestH(A,"JavaFileName".class); 
ColorTee.testh.addFile(C,"/folder1/folder2/folder3/file","myFile")
```

with:

```
ColorTee.testh = new TestH(value1,A,"JavaFileName".class); 
ColorTee.testh.addFile(C,"/folder3/file","myFile")
```

For the second line I would like just to remove `/folder1/folder2`

Comment: What is the solution you want to use? process the files programatically, using java code?

Comment: process the files programatically

Comment: Lazy way : use Eclipse with search/replace tool.

Comment: cl-r, I don't find replace whithin ecplise ?

Comment: cl-r, is there a way from ecplise to add an import of class to all java class to avoid to add it manually for each class ?

Answer (score 0):

You you should do like :

```
String path = "/folder1/folder2/folder3/file";
ColorTee.testh.addFile(C,path,"myFile")
ColorTee.testh.addFile(C,path.replace("/folder1/folder2", ""),"myFile");
```

Comment: with java, I have to create new class and create a method to perform the change ? I would like shell please

Comment: @lola a) so you want me to create a proper class as well as method for you. b) I don't get "*I would like shell ...*"

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Perl script. e.g. here's one I have in my zsh:

```
change () {
        from=$1 
        shift
        to=$1 
        shift
        for file in $*
        do
                perl -i.bak -p -e "s{$from}{$to}g;" $file
                echo "Changing $from to $to in $file"
        done
}
```

and that leverages the shell filename globbing etc. e.g.

```
$ change From To **/*.java
```

An alternative is not to change your method invocations, but change how the method works, and strip the initial path components. That's not so nice, and is also *strongly* dependent upon the actual implementation.

Comment: sorry but I'm not familair with perl , is this a method ?

Comment: The above is a shell function that executes a Perl one-liner. That Perl one-liner reads a given file, changes it and renames the original to whatever.bak

Answer (score 0):

Right from eclipse:

http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/03/how-to-do-global-searchreplace-across/

Comment: Buffalo, how could I do it to apply it only on files available in a specific package but not all ?

Comment: Not sure it's possible only from Eclipse. **However:** you can simply go to Windows Explorer (or whatever file explorer/terminal your OS has), backup the folder corresponding to your package, go back in eclipse and rename what you want, and then restore the backup folder/package to its initial location.